# How to undo Outlook tasks completion?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using Outlook, I created a very simple task just by selecting "New Task" and typing in a subject and clicking "Save & Close". Then, I right clicked the task and selected "Mark Complete". The task now shows as completed in the Tasks folder like this (note the Date Completed column - "11/6/2018"):

[image: Completed Outlook Task]

Or like this in the To-Do List Folder:

[image: Completed Outlook Task - To-Do List]

Now if I uncheck the checkbox to the left of the task on the To-Do list, the task goes back to Active state. The same happens if I right click the completed task and select "Mark Complete" again.

Here is how the reactivated task looks like:

[image: Reactivated Outlook Task]

Next, I mark the task as completed by making either of the two calls to graph api below (from Graph Explorer)

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks({id})

{
   "status": "completed"
}
```

OR

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks({id})/complete
```

Going back to Outlook, everything looks OK, except for the fact that the completion date is now November 5th. I would expect to have the same behavior as before and have November 6th as the completion date. This is the first problem.

The second problem is that if I try to reactivate the task now, it gets to a weird state. I've tried the two reactivation options described above and also tried making a new PATCH call setting the status back to "notStarted". They all produce the same behavior, the task is listed both as Active and as Completed:

This is how the task looks like after the unsuccessful attempt to reactivate it:

In the Tasks folder:
[image]

And In the "To-Do List" folder:
[image]

Is this a bug or am I forgetting anything?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your case on my side. It'd better you can provide the configuration of the new Task too. The date issue maybe caused by the timezone handle logic in API,

Comment: As I said in the post, I don't set anything up, I just create a new Task with some subject. You can do the same thing by sending a POST to the API (https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/outlook/tasks) with this body {"subject":"Some dummy text"}.

Comment: I just tested it again and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

> Going back to Outlook, everything looks OK, except for the fact that
>   the completion date is now November 5th. I would expect to have the
>   same behavior as before and have November 6th as the completion date.
>   This is the first problem.

The date issue maybe caused by the timezone handle logic in API. You can set the datetime explicitly.

```
{
   "status": "completed",
    "completedDateTime": {
        "dateTime": "2018-11-12T00:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    } 
}
```

> The second problem is that if I try to reactivate the task now, it
>   gets to a weird state. I've tried the two reactivation options
>   described above and also tried making a new PATCH call setting the
>   status back to "notStarted". They all produce the same behavior, the
>   task is listed both as Active and as Completed:

Although not sure if it is by design. But, in theory, keep one in the completed list and keep one in to do list is no problem. This can have a track history. **Reactive** is not a good operation behavior too.

Comment: Marking an outlook task as completed has not confirmation dialog. I could just hit the wrong checkbox by accident, so reactivating a task (setting it back to it's previous state) is a reasonable action and necessary one.
Having a task show as both active and complete is conceptually wrong. Yes, there could be ways around it, but none the less, it is still a bug IMHO.

Comment: Hi @Seiya, do you have any updates on this? I would be more then happy to demonstrate this if it would help.